# Можно как-то в xpath прикрутить еще и координаты?

Tags: java, xpath

В автотесте хочу сделать клик по центру объекта. В xpath есть class gwt-CheckBox, но как я понял клик происходит по (0;0) объекта, где он некликабельный, и сам клик мне надо переместить от (0;0) ближе к центру объекта.

`//span[.='Контроль']//..//..//..//[@class='gwt-CheckBox']`
[image: чекбокс]
Подскажите, пожалуйста, как это реализовать или как правильно составить запрос в гугл?
P.S. Попытка нажатия конкретно на `//span[.='Контроль']//..//..//..//[@type='checkbox']` не увенчалась успехом

Comment: `new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele, Xoffset, Yoffset).click().build().perform(); `

Comment: а как определять какие именно значения подставлять в Xoffset и Yoffset?

Comment: ну поставь 2, 2, то есть смещение на 2 пикселя

Comment: это вниз вправо? или вправо вниз? я нуб

Comment: да. начало координат верхний левый угол

Answer (score 0):

```
new Actions(driver).moveToElement(ele, Xoffset, Yoffset).click().build().perform();
```

где, Xoffset смещение по оси X, Yoffset смещение по оси Y

Answer (score 0):

Не пользуюсь Java. Но в принципе думаю что различий быть не должно.
Если вы используете Selenium, то должно происходить одно то же. При поиске элемента на странице вы получаете объект, который содержит много информации об искомом элементе в том числе и его координаты и размеры.
Таким образом рассмотрите получше этот объект и увидите что то ***вроде:***

[image: Вот такой картинки]

Дальше думаю уже понятно. А если бы поделились вашей страничкой, то думаю можно было бы обойтись и без координат.